# Error when passing an extra parameter - BEGINNER

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am getting an error which i have no clue to solve;

The Error : `Unable to load data using the supplied configuration.
Open in Browser: http://localhost/app/p/name.php`

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyJsonPStore1', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.myModel'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.myModel',
        storeId: 'MyJsonPStore1',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://localhost/app/p/name.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'onJsonpstoreBeforeLoad',
                event: 'beforeload'
            }
        ]
    },

    onJsonpstoreBeforeLoad: function(store, operation, eOpts) {

        store.load({
        params: {note: 'HELLO'}
        });


    }

});
```

What returns from `http://localhost/app/p/name.php` is `{"note":"Hell"}`

Answer (score 0):

I have not used jsonp myself (although I admittedly should), but I'm pretty sure you need to have a callback function that wraps your result.

i.e.

```
onJsonpBeforeStoreLoad({
    'note' : 'hell'
})
```

Again, please check my syntax and onJsonpBeforeStoreLoad may verry not be the function name you need to use, you can define that yourself.

I'm sure you have seen this but for anyone who has not: [JSONP Example](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP)